# MYSQL INSERT and JOIN return single result, should return multiple results

Tags: mysql, date, dayofweek

**Table XX**

```
  Day-A       Day-1      Day-B      Day-2    Cat   Dog
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- -----
2018/01/12     NULL      NULL       NULL      Y     N
   NULL        NULL   2018/02/02    NULL      N     Y
   NULL        NULL   2018/01/26    NULL      N     Y
   NULL    2018/01/15    NULL       NULL      Y     N
   NULL        NULL      NULL    2018/01/15   N     Y
   NULL        NULL   2018/01/19    NULL      N     Y
```

I would like to match Day-A and Day-B, and Day-1 and Day-2. Day-A and Day-1 will be tagged as 'Cat', while Day-B and Day-2 will be tagged as 'Dog'. 'Cat' always matched with 'Dog'

- Day-A and Day-B need to be matched by day e.g. Monday = Monday.
- Day-1 and Day-2 need to be matched by same date.

I can do the Day-1 and Day-2 match, but not another one.

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Day-A, Day-1, Day-B, Day-2, c.Cat, d.Dog)
SELECT c.Day-A, c.Day-1, d.Day-B, d.Day-2
FROM calendar AS c
    LEFT JOIN calendar AS d
    ON ((IFNULL(c.Day-1, 'x') = IFNULL(d.Day-2, 'x')
    AND IFNULL(DAYNAME(c.Day-A), 'x') = IFNULL(DAYNAME(d.Day-B), 'x'))
    WHERE c.Cat = d.Dog
```

I matched Day-1 and Day-2 but not another pair.
Only the closest date is showing up.
In my case only 2018/01/19 is showed, but not 2018/1/26 nor 2018/02/02, though they are all Friday.
 Day-A and Day-B can be several months different in my table.

**My desired table result:**

```
Id     Day-A       Day-1      Day-B      Day-2    Cat    Dog
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  -----  -----
 1  2018/01/12     NULL   2018/01/19     NULL      Y      Y
 2  2018/01/12     NULL   2018/01/26     NULL      Y      Y
 3  2018/01/12     NULL   2018/02/02     NULL      Y      Y
 4     NULL    2018/01/15     NULL    2018/01/15   Y      Y
```

Is it possible to have more than one result for DAYNAME() match?

Comment: Edit your question to show the query you have tried, the one that only shows one match on Day-A and Day-B. Also, edit your question to show the table schema/name

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you for correcting me. Now it is better for everybody to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually quite close. [I built an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65b342/6) and populated it with your data. The query you gave above produced the following result:

```
Day_A       Day_1       Day_B       Day_2       Cat    Dog
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-02-02  (null)      Y      Y
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-01-26  (null)      Y      Y
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      (null)      (null)      (null)      N      N
(null)      2018-01-15  (null)      2018-01-15  Y      Y
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-01-19  (null)      Y      Y
```

At first glance this looks nothing like the desired results, until you realize that the only difference is all the lines with NULL values in DAY_A, DAY_1, DAY_B, and DAY_2. So if we eliminate the rows where DAY_A, DAY_1, DAY_B, and DAY_2 are all NULL we should be good:

```
SELECT c.Day_A, c.Day_1, d.Day_B, d.Day_2, c.Cat, d.Dog
  FROM calendar AS c
  LEFT JOIN calendar AS d
    ON IFNULL(c.Day_1, 'x') = IFNULL(d.Day_2, 'x') AND
       IFNULL(DAYNAME(c.Day_A), 'x') = IFNULL(DAYNAME(d.Day_B), 'x')
  WHERE c.Cat = d.Dog AND
        (c.DAY_A IS NOT NULL OR
         c.DAY_1 IS NOT NULL OR
         d.DAY_B IS NOT NULL OR
         d.DAY_2 IS NOT NULL)
```

which produces

```
Day_A       Day_1       Day_B       Day_2       Cat    Dog
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-02-02  (null)      Y      Y
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-01-26  (null)      Y      Y
(null)      2018-01-15  (null)      2018-01-15  Y      Y
2018-01-12  (null)      2018-01-19  (null)      Y      Y
```

which seems to be what was wanted.

Best of luck.

Comment: For SELECT it works as intended, but not with INSERT INTO.

Comment: All you have to do is add the INSERT part of your query to this select, then it should work as you asked.

Comment: I found my mistake of setting wrong primary key, thus the INSERT only insert 1 value.